# Building Large Number from JSON

Tags: javascript, integer, concatenation

At the moment I receive JSON with objects. Each object has 4 strings which contain 3 digits. I need to construct a large number from those digits. For example if the digits are "111", "222", "333", and "444" the number should be 1112222333444. Since I need ===1112222333444 to be true, I can't do direct string concatenation because the result wouldn't be an integer. What is my fastest option for transforming this JSON to a number containing only the concatenated integers? I also want to ignore the first 5-6 digits if they are zeros.

Comment: Can't you do the concatenation and then parse to number?

Comment: concatenate as string and then parseInt?

Answer (score 3):

You can just concatenate them and then convert them to a Number

```
Number("111" + "222" + "333" + "444") === 111222333444  // true
```

or shorter

```
+("111" + "222" + "333" + "444") === 111222333444  // true
```

This even works if some groups are zero, because Number or "+" just interprets the String as a number and doesn't do any parsing (opposite to parseInt, which will parse "010" to 8, if no radix is given, because it interprets numbers with leading zeros as octal. There are also some other differences)

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = str1 + str2 + str3 + str4;
var result = Number(str);
```

This way you parse the string into the number type. It also discards leading zeroes.